# Update section of static UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, static, tableview

I hope someone can help...

I've setup a static UITableView Controller with four sections. The top two sections are for inputting data. The third section has 1 cell and contains a save button.

The final section has 6 cells and I want to be able to populate these six cells with the data from the first two sections, in the long run anyway...

So i tried to a small example, but it's not working. The console returns the following error:

> UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Here's an example:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NSIndexPath *EditRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:4];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:EditRow];

    NSString *test = @"Test";
    cell.textLabel.text = test;

    NSLog(@"Index Path: %d", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"Cell ID:, %@", CellIdentifier);

    return cell;
}
```

So my question comes down to.. How do I update a specific cell in a  specific section?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I implement static cells, I delete the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, and `numberOfRowsInSection` methods from the generic `UIViewController` stub that Xcode generates; these seem to be necessary only when you're dealing with dynamic cells.

Then, by control-dragging in the storyboard, I create named outlets for all UI elements in the cells that need to be set programmatically; in my case, these are usually `UILabel`s. In the `viewDidLoad` method of the controller, I set the appropriate initial values of these outlets, for example:

```
self.nameLabel.text = self.dataSource.name;
```

Once you've got this wired up, you can change any of the values at will.

I hope that this works for you. I'd be happy to learn from anyone who has a better (more appropriate?) way of doing this.

Comment: Your way is the correct way. With static cells, the table is created by the base implementations of the datasource methods (I.e. those in UITableViewController), so overriding them is tricky unless you know what you're doing. It's a fine line between static cells with editable content, and dynamic tables, and outlets are the way to go.

Comment: ... with the exception that the outlets aren't connected until _after_ [super viewWillAppear:] is called. viewDidLoad isn't a good place to set label text and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call - [UITableView (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation], then your data source will be called for the appropriate index paths.

Comment: Hello,thanksnfor getting back to me. Do you have an example of this by any chance?